# Can we run Dataproc just on GKE or private on-prem k8s as well?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-dataproc

I would like understand if someone has tried running Dataproc on a private k8s cluster rather than on GKE or if its even possible given the current developments so far?

Answer (score 3):

Currently Dataproc on GKE cannot run on private-master cluster (including private-master GKE clusters). This is something we plan to support eventually (probably pre-GA), as well as supporting deployments to any Anthos managed Kubernetes cluster.

Also note that there are currently no plans to support Dataproc running on Kubernetes clusters that are not managed by GKE or Anthos.

Comment: When is GA release? Is there a timeline available I can follow?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no publicly committed timeline for this yet.

You can follow public updates through the [release notes feed](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/release-notes). The [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/jobs/dataproc-gke) for this feature will also be updated when it becomes available.

Comment: Is it still the case that it can't run on private master clusters? Is it documented somewhere?